# enter values in html and send to mysql database, before that multiply

Tags: php, html

I have come to an obstacle and don't know how to proceed. In my html site user enter some data first data is dropdown box which is populated from number in database, so the user only selects here, second number you need to input and 3th number you need to input. 4th field is just random text for now.

What i would like to do is somehow multiply the number selected from dropdown box and the number which user inputs first and then save that number in a same row in which i save this input.

This is what i have so far:
HTML:

```
<form action="dodajanje_stevcev2.php" method="post">
Dropdown box: <select id="denominacija" type="number" step="0.001" name="denominacija" onchange="myFunction()">
```

//here is the php for dropdown box, which works fine

```
Enter 1st num: <input type="number" name="stava" /><br><br>
Enter 2nd num: <input type="number" name="dobitek"  /><br><br>
Vrsta stave (please enter text): <input type="text"name="vrsta_stave" /><br><br>
</select>
<input type="submit", value="Poslji" />
</form>
```

PHP:

//here comes connection

```
echo "Connected successfully";
$total_in=$POST['denominacija'] * $POST['stava']; /this is where i am stuck
$sql = "INSERT INTO stevci (denominacija, stava, dobitek,vrsta_stave, total_in, date_time)
VALUES
('$_POST[denominacija]', '$_POST[stava]','$_POST[dobitek]','$_POST[vrsta_stave]','$total_in', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() )";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
header('Location: dodajanje_stevcev.php'); exit;
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}$conn->close();

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi found an answer myself:

```
$de = $_POST['denominacija']; 
$st = $_POST['denominacija'];
$total_in=$de * $st;
```